# Getting a prop.table() in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been trying to use prop.table() to get the proportions of data I have but keep getting errors.  My data is..

```
Letter   Total
a        10
b        34
c        8
d        21
.        .
.        .
.        .
z        2
```

I want a third column that gives the proportion of each letter.
My original data is in a data frame so I've tried converting to a data table and then using prop.table ..

```
testtable = table(lettersdf)
prop.table(testtable)
```

When I try this I keep getting the error,

```
Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array
```

Any help or advise is appreciated.

:)

Comment: Try `lettersdf$prop <- prop.table(lettersdf[, 2])`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What is the result of `class(lettersdf)`?

Comment: Please provide a self contained R code for us to solve this for.

Comment: This question should not be tagged data.table.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Letter` column in your data does not have duplicate values, like this

```
Df <- data.frame(
  Letter=letters,
  Total=sample(1:50,26),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

you can just do this instead of using `prop.table`:

```
Df$Prop <- Df$Total/sum(Df$Total)
> head(Df)
  Letter Total        Prop
1      a    45 0.074875208
2      b     1 0.001663894
3      c    13 0.021630616
4      d    15 0.024958403
5      e    24 0.039933444
6      f    39 0.064891847
> sum(Df[,3])
[1] 1
```

If there are duplicated values, like in this object

```
Df2 <- data.frame(
  Letter=sample(letters,50,replace=T),
  Total=sample(1:50,50),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

you can make a `table` to sum the frequency of unique `Letter`s,

```
Table <- table(rep(Df2$Letter,Df2$Total))
> Table
  a   b   c   d   e   f   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   t   v   w   x   y   z 
 48  16  99   2  40  75  45  42  66   6  62  27  88  99  32  96  85  64  53 161  69
```

and then use `prop.table` on this `table` object:

```
> prop.table(Table)
          a           b           c           d           e           f           h           j           k           l           m 
0.037647059 0.012549020 0.077647059 0.001568627 0.031372549 0.058823529 0.035294118 0.032941176 0.051764706 0.004705882 0.048627451 
          n           o           p           q           t           v           w           x           y           z 
0.021176471 0.069019608 0.077647059 0.025098039 0.075294118 0.066666667 0.050196078 0.041568627 0.126274510 0.054117647
```

You could also make this into a `data.frame`:

```
Df2.table <- cbind(
  data.frame(Table,stringsAsFactors=F),
  Prop=as.numeric(prop.table(Table)))
> head(Df2.table)
  Var1 Freq        Prop
1    a   48 0.037647059
2    b   16 0.012549020
3    c   99 0.077647059
4    d    2 0.001568627
5    e   40 0.031372549
6    f   75 0.058823529
```