# How do I get a prop.table in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I've been looking at a question that is wrongly tagged as `data.table`. Here: [prop.table() error in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454499/prop-table-error-in-r) 
I'm looking to get a proportions table but I've so far done so with no luck. Here is sample data and code:

```
library(data.table)
data(Arthritis,package="vcd")
#mytable<-with(Arthritis,table(Improved))
#mytable
mydata2<-copy(Arthritis)
setDT(mydata2)
head(mydata2)
mydata2[,.(.N),by=.(Improved)]
mydata2[,lapply(.N,sum),by=.(Improved)]
```

This yields:

```
   Improved V1
1:     Some 14
2:     None 42
3:   Marked 28
```

I thought simply chaining like this would help but it returns interesting output:

```
mydata2[,lapply(.N,sum),by=.(Improved)][,prop:=V1/sum(V1)]
```

What is a simple exclusively `data.table` way to get a proportions table?

Comment: I think you need to do `mydata2[, c("Improved", "V1") := lapply(.N,sum),by=Improved]` on the first part.

Comment: It's the assignment by reference that will allow you to add the `prop` column in the next block

Comment: Yeah. My bad! Thanks again!

Comment: There is no reason to lapply on .N since it is a single value, so you could just do `mydata2[, .N, by=.(Improved)][, prop := N/sum(N)][]`

Comment: Thanks @Frank That is also a nice one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"We don't need no steenking counts."  # classic movie reference

I think you must have some sort of conceptual barrier to understanding the "true power" of the second argument position of the `[.data.table` function. You just put an expression to be evaluated. Since prop.table expects a table object, you must first construct one with the `table` function:

```
mydata2[ , prop.table(table(Improved)) ]
Improved
     None      Some    Marked 
0.5000000 0.1666667 0.3333333
```

I do note that the returned value is *not* a data.table object.

Comment: Thanks. That's so simple. I'm just starting to learn `data.table`

Comment: It is quite simple. My experience with the use of table inside large data.tables was disappointing. I found that tabulations went faster on the equivalent dataframes. That experience was several years ago, so it might have been addressed already. I did report that surprising finding to the package author.

Comment: `porp.table` and `table` are just ordinary base functions. Unless someone will write some specific method for `data.table` there is no real reason to expect them to work faster than in a `data.frame`. If you really want to use `data.table`s power you can just use `data.table` functionality instead- See Franks comment, for instance- it should be faster by several factors than `prop.table(table())` combo for big data sets.

Comment: Please read what I said. I would have expected the speed to be comparable to the speed obtained when using table on a dataframe, since `data.table` objects are supposed to inherit the `data.frame` class. My experience was that it was significantly SLOWER. That was what was surprising.